# Android alarm troubles

Tags: java, android, alarm

I'm making a simple reminder app on android.

I've got a date such as 27-06-2011 (DD-MM-YY) and I wish to create an alarm at this date (at 12:01AM).

I know this is possible, but how easy is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer from [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=android%20alarm%20tutorial) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), 10 * 1000, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you need to use the date you mentionned, create a Time objet, set the fields using its constructor and use time.toMillis( false); to get the right paramter for the alarm manager.

Regards,
 Stéphane